# WCF dependency injection without SVC file

Tags: c#, wcf, inversion-of-control

I have a WCF service which is exposed via net.pipe. This service is hosted like so:

```
var hosturi = new Uri("net.pipe://localhost/somewhere");
var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service), hosturi);
var serviceBinding = new NetNamedPipeBinding
{
    MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue, // and maybe something else
};

serviceBinding.ReaderQuotas = new System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas
{
    MaxArrayLength = int.MaxValue, // and maybe something else
};

host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(T), serviceBinding, string.Empty);
host.Description.Behaviors.Add(
    new ServiceThrottlingBehavior
    {
        MaxConcurrentCalls = 5000,
        MaxConcurrentInstances = 5000,
        MaxConcurrentSessions = 5000
    }
);
host.Open();
```

I want to specify the DI factory for my Service instance gets any constructor dependencies injected.

While there is plenty of articles on the subject (e.g. here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh323725(v=vs.100).aspx) absolutely all of them suggest specifying the Factory using the .svc file.

How can I do this in code?

Comment: @Evk You helped me a lot! That worked. If you add your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create service host yourself so you don't need ServiceHostFactory (which is a factory to create ServceHost). So just skip steps 4-6 from the article and add behaviour to your host with

```
host.Description.Behaviors.Add(new DependencyInjectionServiceBehavior());
```